# Putting page numbers in left/right margin in Memoir class

Tags: margins, memoir, page-numbering

A [very similar issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446031) has been asked quite a while ago. Although, my goal is not to put the page numbers in the header, but in the side margin. I am using the `twoside` and `a5paper` options in LaTeX Memoir.

Is there a similar approach to that one mentioned as an answer to the linked issue? I found a [solution using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94430/) here, but is there a way of achieving this directly by using Memoir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified the answer that you refer to.

```
% pagenumberprob.tex SE 561745   --- a modification of the answer to SE 446031
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{picture}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

%% Make headers what I want (don't say Chapter 1 chap 1 etc)
%\createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{\hspace{3mm}}
%\createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{\hspace{3mm}}

%% new page style
\makepagestyle{myvf}
\pagestyle{myvf}

%% line to show where page actually ends
%\makeheadrule{myvf}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}

% use a zero sized picture to place the page number
\newcommand{\shiftpage}{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0){\put(0,-2.7\baselineskip){\textbf{\thepage}}}\end{picture}%
}

%% attempt at header where page number exists in the margin - alternating left and right
\makeevenhead{myvf}{\llap{\shiftpage\hspace{2\marginparsep}}\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{myvf}{}{}{\rightmark\rlap{\hspace{2\marginparsep}\shiftpage}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chap 1}

\section{sec 1}
\lipsum[1-15]

\section{sec 2}

\end{document}
```

You may want to adjust the location of the page numbers and their font.

Comment: That worked perfectly! So I assume there is not really a good way to do it without using a picture to move the number around? Then this idea is actually quite similar to the TikZ solution linked above, right?

Comment: @TiMauzi A zero sized `picture` is a good way to put things where you want them to be.